# Does std::atomic prevent reordering of nonatomic variables over the atomic variables

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

question is rather simple Q:
If I have

```
settings[N_STNGS];//used by many threads  
std::atomic<size_t> current_settings(0);
void updateSettings()//called by single thread  , always the same thread if that is important
{

    auto new_settings = (current_settings+1)%N_STNGS;
    settings[new_settings].loadFromFileSystem(); //line A
    current_settings=new_settings; //line B
}
```

does standard guarantee that line A wont be reordered after line B? Also will users of STNGS always see consistent(commited-as in memory visibility visible) data?

Edit: for multiple reader threads and nontrivial settings is this worth the trouble compared to simple mutexing?

Comment: Even if it's not, this code is absolutely broken. (`current_settings` can be changed by other thread between the first line and the last line.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz : consider char padding[padding_size]; at the beginning and at the end of struct. Also STNGS can be pointer arraythat never changes, just the pointed to stuff does...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Is this a C++ question or a question about some particular platform? If it's a C++ question, there's no guarantee padding is all you need. If it's a platform-specific question, the answer will depend on the platform. (You are correct about `settings` never changing.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What you say is false for C++11, different array members can be accessed concurrently without worries.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz x86-64 is the platform

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Really. Quoting 1.3/7: "A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-ﬁelds all having
non-zero width. Two threads of execution (1.10) can update and access separate memory locations
without interfering with each other."

Comment: @jpalacek That is in fact what the standard says! I wonder how you are supposed to implement `char` arrays on SMP RISC systems.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz can you explain why pointers solve the problem... I mean cant it be that 2 malloced regions have the same problem like normal array. Though much less likely.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl The `malloc` implementation would be smart enough to issue only regions that cannot conflict. Typically, they don't even have to do anything special since the alignment requirements on `malloc` are sufficient already.

Answer (score 2):

Given the definition

```
int settings[N_STNGS];
std::atomic<size_t> current_settings(0);
```

and Thread 1 executing:

```
settings[new_settings] = somevalue;  // line A
current_settings=new_settings;       // line B
```

and Thread 2 executing:

```
int cur_settings = current_settings;        // line X
int setting_value = settings[cur_settings]; // line Y
```

then yes, if Thread 2 at line X reads `new_settings` written by Thread 1 in line B, and there are no other modifications to `settings[new_settings]` (by some code we don't see), Thread 2 is bound to read `somevalue` and no undefined behavior occurs. This is because all the operations are (by default) `memory_order_seq_cst` and a release-write (line B) synchronizes with an acquire-read (line X). Note that you need two statements in Thread 2 to get a sequenced-before relationship between the atomic read of the index and the read of the value (a `memory_order_consume` operation would do instead).

I'd certainly implement it with rw-mutexes for start.

Comment: I agree. Line X can either read the initial value 0 or one of the values written by B, in which case there is a happens-before relation between B and X. A happens before B by program order, and  X happens before Y. Since the happens-before relationship is transitive, A happens before Y. It doesn't matter that code in A and Y is not atomic. The only worry is the use of a cyclic buffer. It's theoretically possible that `current_settings` wraps around between lines X and Y. That would cause a data race between A and Y.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski wraping around is extremely unlikely because update settings is done like every couple of seconds, so that would be some stealth memory visibility model(I mean it would be the worst cache coherency CPU model ever) in which it would be a problem.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you are commenting on the settings *content*, or just the index of the circular array of settings.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski BTW i have atomic<bool> is_initialized in the settings, so for example public method bool  isBlocked() will always return false if settings havent been filled at least once.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Lines A and Y set the contents. Lines B and X provide necessary synchronization and ensure that contents operations are synchronized too. What's important is that *all* readers must first read cur_settings and then the contents. If you like to think in terms of fences/barriers, B and X provide the fencing.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I would rather initialize `currentSettings` to N_STNGS and check that every time. This way you have only one synchronization variable.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is no. If you are careful and you use only functions which have a `memory_order` parameter and pass them the right value for it depending on what you are doing, then it may be yes.

(And as other have pointed out, your code has problems. For instance, returning by value an atomic<> type doesn't make sense for me.)