# C++: __sync_synchronize() still needed with std::atomic?

Tags: c++, linux, atomic

I've been running into an infrequent but re-occurring race condition.
The program has two threads and uses std::atomic. I'll simplify the critical parts of the code to look like:

```
std::atomic<uint64_t> b;  // flag, initialized to 0
uint64_t data[100];  // shared data, initialized to 0
```

**thread 1 (publishing):**

```
// set various shared variables here, for example
data[5] = 10;

uint64_t a = b.exchange(1);  // signal to thread 2 that data is ready
```

**thread 2 (receiving):**

```
if (b.load() != 0) {  // signal that data is ready
  // read various shared variables here, for example:
  uint64_t x = data[5];
  // race condition sometimes (x sometimes not consistent)
}
```

The odd thing is that when I add __sync_synchronize() to each thread, then the race condition goes away. I've seen this happen on two different servers.

i.e. when I change the code to look like the following, then the problem goes away:

**thread 1 (publishing):**

```
// set various shared variables here, for example
data[5] = 10;

__sync_synchronize();
uint64_t a = b.exchange(1);  // signal to thread 2 that data is ready
```

**thread 2 (receiving):**

```
if (b.load() != 0) {  // signal that data is ready
  __sync_synchronize();
  // read various shared variables here, for example:
  uint64_t x = data[5];
}
```

Why is __sync_synchronize() necessary? It seems redundant as I thought both exchange and load ensured the correct sequential ordering of logic.

Architecture is x86_64 processors, linux, g++ 4.6.2

Comment: You've overly simplified your problem. Whatever the issue is, it's probably outside of the code snippets you've shown, or in the code you've removed and marked with comments.

Comment: The comments were to give a bigger picture understanding of what's happening. But the simpler question is why would adding __sync_synchronize() immediately after a load() in the receiving thread and adding __sync_synchronize() immediately before an exchange in the publishing thread fix the problem when it seems like those lines are redundant?

Comment: Are "various shared variables" std::atomic as well?

Comment: The short answer is that it doesn't/shouldn't. `std::atomic` already makes memory model guarantees, and shouldn't require any additional synchronization. So if you're still observing Race Conditions, that probably means there's a problem with how you've ordered the other code with respect to these synchronization points.

Comment: You do not provide enough information (what are "shared variable" and how you access it) not to mention [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst it is impossible to say from your simplified code what actually goes on in your actual application, the fact that `__sync_synchronize` helps, and the fact that this function is a memory barrier tells me that you are writing things in the one thread that the other thread is reading, in a way that isn't atomic.

An example:

```
thread_1:

    object *p = new object;
    p->x = 1;
    b.exchange(p);   /* give pointer p to other thread */

thread_2:

    object *p = b.load();
    if (p->x == 1) do_stuff();
    else error("Huh?");
```

This may very well trigger the error-path in thread2, because the write to `p->x` has not actually been completed when thread 2 reads the new pointer value p.

Adding memory barrier, in this case, in the thread_1 code should fix this. Note that for THIS case, a memory barrier in thread_2 will not do anything - it may alter the timing and appear to fix the problem, but it won't be the right thing. You may need memory barriers on both sides still, if you are reading/writing memory that is shared between two threads.

I understand that this may not be precisely what your code is doing, but the concept is the same - `__sync_synchronize` ensures that memory reads and memory writes have completed for ALL of the instructions before that function call [which isn't a real function call, it will inline a single instruction that waits for any pending memory operations to comlete].

Noteworthy is that operations on `std::atomic` ONLY affect the actual data stored in the atomic object. Not reads/writes of other data.

Sometimes you also need a "compiler barrier" to avoid the compiler moving stuff from one side of an operation to another:

```
  std::atomic<bool> flag(false);
  value = 42;
  flag.store(true);

  ....
```

another thread:

```
  while(!flag.load());
  print(value);
```

Now, there is a chance that the compiler generates the first form as:

```
  flag.store(true);
  value = 42;
```

Now, that wouldn't be good, would it? std::atomic is guaranteed to be a "compiler barrier", but in other cases, the compiler may well shuffle stuff around in a similar way.

Comment: "Whilst it is impossible to say from your simplified code" maybe it is better to make OP to edit question rather than rush with an answer?

Comment: It's a pretty strong chance that the problem is "other data being written" tho'.

Comment: Is that a good reason to promote creating of badly formulated questions?

Comment: @Slava But if the questioner doesn't know where the question falls short, this answer will help.  And it's certainly too much for a comment...

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the other data being written to. I thought std::atomic was sufficient to use as a synchronization method between different threads (ensuring loads/stores to other variables were in sync), but your examples and explanation (which are similar to what's happening) would explain the problem.

Comment: Also, this seems to be different from cppreference which states "In addition, accesses to atomic objects may establish inter-thread synchronization and order non-atomic memory accesses as specified by std::memory_order." and inconsistent with Slava's earlier comment that "std::atomic already makes memory model guarantees, and shouldn't require any additional synchronization"

Comment: So if we have something like:
uint64_t data[100];  // initialize all to 0
std::atomic<uint64_t> my_flag;  // initialize to 0

thread 1:
data[5] = 10;
my_flag.exchange(1);

thread 2:
while (my_flag.load() != 1);
x = data[5];

It's possible that x would not read 10?

Comment: Yes, very much possible.

Comment: @Switch: You would make a much better question if you added that bit of code to the question itself.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Okay thanks. I added more detail to the original question. I will say, this seems quite different from other answers to somewhat related questions like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8793476/205938 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692735/205938 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/30540127/205938 (are those answers incorrect? Doesn't memory_order_seq_cst mean the race condition shouldn't happen?). Also, is __sync_synchronize() the preferred approach to dealing with this?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, it seems like it ought to work without __sync_synchronize(), so it may be a bug in that version of the compiler. If you have access to a newer compiler [or different, e.g. clang], you may want to try that [even if it's just to prove that it is compiler-dependent]. I've not got much time to look into this right now, and I haven't got a 4.6.2 compiler on any of my machines.

Comment: "std::atomic is guaranteed to be a "compiler barrier", but in other cases, the compiler may well shuffle stuff around in a similar way." <-- I think with the correct (depending on what the code is trying to do) memory orders specified in the `store()` and `load()`, the "shuffle" is acceptable and expected, no?